# How to get qpid broker URL programmatically?

Tags: jms, spring-jms, qpid

So I have a ConnectionFactory configured from a properties file containing a broker list, meaning that when the session gets created it will have connected to one of the brokers in the list based on availability/policy and so on.

My question is: how to programmatically figure out from the Java code, at runtime, which of the broker URLs have I actually connected to.

What I am trying to achieve is to send management GET requests to the broker API programmatically, but for that I need to obtain its URL. Am I thinking about this the wrong way?

P.S. I am doing this from a Spring-boot application, but am not too fussed about using the JmsTemplate.

Comment: Which Qpid Client are you using?   There are two Qpid JMS Client: https://qpid.apache.org/components/jms/ (which uses AMQP 1.0) or https://qpid.apache.org/components/jms/security-0-x.html (the older AMQP protocols).

Comment: The latter, I believe. AMQP 0.9